# How to implement conditional statement in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown and like to condition my choices.If the user click check box the div for checkbox will appear else the radio button is click then it will appear.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhvds925/2/

```js
function selectorchecker() {

  if (selectorchecker == "checkbox") {
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("chkbox_choice");
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "") ? "none" : "block";
  } else {
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("rdbtn_choice");
    hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "") ? "none" : "block";

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Question:
  <br>

  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description" placeholder="Enter a question">
         </textarea>
  <br>

  <select name="choice" id="choice" onchange="selectorchecker()">
    <option value="">Select choices</option>
    <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
    <option value="radiobtn">Radio Button</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button id="addQues">Add Question</button>

<div style="display:none;" id="chkbox_choice">
  <table id="dataTable" width="350px">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" /></td>
      <td>
        <INPUT type="text" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" value="Add choices" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

  <input type="button" value="Delete choices" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
</div>


<div style="display:none;" id="rdbtn_choice">
  <table id="dataTable" width="350px">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radio" /></td>
      <td>
        <INPUT type="text" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" value="Add choices" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

  <input type="button" value="Delete choices" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can try this way: https://jsfiddle.net/2tov1zjc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
function selectorchecker(sel) {
  document.getElementById("chkbox_choice").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("rdbtn_choice").style.display = "none";
  if (sel.value) {
    var show = sel.value=="checkbox"?"chkbox_choice":"rdbtn_choice";
    document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Question:
  <br>

  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description" placeholder="Enter a question">
         </textarea>
  <br>

  <select name="choice" id="choice" onchange="selectorchecker(this)">
    <option value="">Select choices</option>
    <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
    <option value="radiobtn">Radio Button</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button id="addQues">Add Question</button>

<div style="display:none;" id="chkbox_choice">
  <table id="dataTable" width="350px">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" /></td>
      <td>
        <INPUT type="text" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" value="Add choices" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

  <input type="button" value="Delete choices" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
</div>


<div style="display:none;" id="rdbtn_choice">
  <table id="dataTable" width="350px">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="radio" /></td>
      <td>
        <INPUT type="text" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" value="Add choices" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

  <input type="button" value="Delete choices" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have using the right things but one thing had missed in that. you didn't define the selectorchecker variable, So that's why this condition is not working please pass one change function something like this

```
onchange="selectorchecker(this)"
```

function selectorchecker(selector){

```
var selectorchecker = $(selector).val();
if (selectorchecker=="checkbox"){
var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("chkbox_choice");
hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "") ? "none":"block";
}
else {
 var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("rdbtn_choice");
hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value == "") ? "none":"block";

}

}
```

and use your function like that, this will definitely work for you thank you.

Comment: That will show the radio when there is no selection after a selection